# Codeigniter or Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

Yes, I am aware one is a framework and the other a CMS.

However, I am a one man team that develops projects/websites for myself and I have a limited amount of time to get these projects off the ground, so speed is crucial.

Basically I am looking for the easiest and fastest method for creating web apps without being limited on features.

Would it be best/fastest to learn Codeigniter or to build off of Wordpress and develop my own themes/plugins? Possibly another option that would be more viable?

I deal a lot with video/photo media and high traffic websites.

Thanks!

Comment: This question was closed by multiple people, but I believe this was an important question that many people are curious about, especially single man teams. Under the questions FAQ, it states to ask questions that cover "a specific programming problem", which for me, this clearly did. Should I spend my VALUABLE single person time perfecting codeigniter or wordpress. I understand nobody got the chance to type in any exciting brackets in my question, but I disagree with the "off topic" closing.

Comment: Just an update, it's 4 years later and I learned both and still use both today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest using CodeIgniter. The logic is simple, and it doesn't really have limitations, unlike WordPress. WordPress is designed for blogs, and if you are looking for flexibility, I would go with CodeIgniter.

CodeIgniter has one of the best documentation available as well. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html

If you are looking to learn CodeIgniter, NetTuts has some great tutorials, with different levels.
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/

There are some nifty CodeIgniter libraries that can get you head start on your projects:

- https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth - Ion Auth, CodeIgniter Authentication Library
- http://www.kaydoo.co.uk/projects/backendpro - Backend Pro, designed to build admin side of your application.

If you are looking for CodeIgniter based blog/CMS, I would also suggest PyroCMS, one of the best I've used.
http://pyrocms.com/

CodeIgniter also has a great image manipulation library built in, so you won't have to learn too much about generic PHP image libraries.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Answer (score 6):

If what you develop is web applications, especially for high-traffic sites, then why not to also consider Doctrine? It is a really good framework for developing webapps. Regarding WordPress - if what you need is mostly webapps with extensive user interaction and complex data structures - WP can't handle that efficiently due to lack of ORM and MVC pattern support (there are a couple of workarounds, but anyway).

And if you're open to learn new languages - also consider learning RubyOnRails and Django - both are awesome platforms, documented well and having awesome communities.

Comment: Your response was also helpful, thank you, I will look into doctrine

Comment: And also take a look at Symphony framework :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with tpae. Definitely WP is not meant to be used for web apps. So forget about it.

CI is great, easy to learn, and in combo with [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and Phil's [REST_Controller](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/03/video-set-up-a-rest-api-with-codeigniter) it's a beauty to work with :) You'll be building highly responsive web apps in no time (this sounds like a commercial :D )

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will checking out both of your links.